# Different backgrounds on jQuery UI's dialog boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, background-image

I need to make 3 different backgrounds for some dialog box.
First, i don't want the "common" title on the dialog box, i removed it.
 
i want to use a simple background-image instead of the css proposed by the jquery css.
Nonetheless, i used the jquery css and added background-image to .ui-dialog.
how do i change the background-image on the 'iu-dialog' with js?

Comment: this should be tagged as jquery-ui; for some reason I can't add this.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to it, either manually or using jQuery in case you wanted to have a series of the same-looking dialogs:

```
$('.selector').addClass("dialog_alt");
```

Then throw the background-image into the css, make it important?

```
.dialog_alt{
    background-image: url(image.png) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background-image via JavaScript/jQuery you can do it with:

`$('.ui-dialog').css('background-image', 'some/image.png')`.

More information about [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Downvoting without adding a comment, it is not useful at all :(